# Why is this query slow?

Tags: mysql, performance

I was looking my slow query logs today and saw this:

```
# Time: 2017-11-22T10:37:55.752360Z
# User@Host: somename[somename] @  [Some IP]  Id:   123
# Query_time: 13.734802  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1511347075;
SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`responsavel_id`, 
`Extent1`.`condominio_id`, 
`Extent1`.`cliente_pai_id`, 
`Extent1`.`valor`, 
`Extent1`.`empresa`
FROM `clientes_responsavel_relacao` AS `Extent1`
WHERE `Extent1`.`condominio_id` = 1234 LIMIT 1;
```

Queries like those should be extremely quick, no? I don't know much about how to configure a MYSQL database, but I'm pretty positive that we use a mostly default setup.

Any hints?

By the way, the table has only those columns and less than 1000 rows.

If it helps, we use ASP.NET webforms and the last stable connector .NET together with Dapper in some places and Entity Framework in others.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the fields in the WHERE condition?

Comment: Small system, not enough memory or cpu?  What does your mysql server look like when you run that query from a usage standpoint?  I agree this query has nothing crazy about it...

Comment: If there is only this single out-of-the-blue entry personally I would not worry about it unless it occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an index:

```
CREATE INDEX id_index ON clientes_responsavel_relacao (condominio_id) USING BTREE;
```